# Meteor.user().emails[0].address を取得できるも、Type Error が出てしまう

Tags: meteor

こんにちは。Meteor初心者です。

アカウントに関する質問です。
パッケージは accounts-password と meteor add accounts-ui を使っています。

currentUser のメールアドレスに応じて、見せる画面を変えたいと思っています。
以下のようなコードを、client側のヘルパー関数の中に置いて実行してみました。

```
1 var address = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
2 console.log(address); // for debug
3 if (address == 'a@b.com') { ... }
```

これで、結果は思った通りになります。
2 の結果として、コンソールにアドレスが表示され、
3 の条件分岐は期待通りに動きます。

ところが、コンソールに、次のようなメッセージが出てしまいます。

"Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined"

あるいは、undefined が null の場合もあります。
（この後に長いメッセージが続くのですが、割愛します）

何か、おかしなことが起きているのでしょうか。
この Exception が出ないようにするには、どうすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。単に、戻り値の変数の型チェックをしていなかっただけでした。すみません。

その後、クライアント側ではなくサーバ側のMeteor.publishの中で実行するようにして、
if (this.userId) {...} のチェックをしてOKです。

Comment: 解決したことすぐに分かるのでベストアンサーにしておくと良いと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。